# Add animations on click button with keyframes

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have a button and when I click on it, a div appear with a keyframe animation.
But I would like to have the same animation (opacity and height) when we click one more time to 'close' this div.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $('div').removeClass('In');
    $("div").css({ "visibility": "hidden" });
    $(this).text("Open ↓");
    $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  } else {
    $('div').addClass('In');
    $("div").css({ "visibility": "visible" });
    $(this).text("Close ↑");
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  text - align: center
}

div {
  display: inline - block;
  background: pink;
  height: 300 px;
  width: 300 px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

button {
  font - size: 16 px;
}

@keyframes In {
  0 % {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0
  }
  100 % {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300 px
  }
}

.In {
  animation - duration: 800 ms;
  animation - name: In;
  animation - delay: 0 s;
}
```

```html
<button>Open ↓ </button> <br>
<div> </div>
```

(Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84La3pqb/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add another class for out action. We can add opacity in the class itself

```js
$('button').click(function() {
 var el = $(this);
 setTimeout(function() {
  if (el.hasClass("clicked")) {
   $('div').removeClass('In');
   $('div').addClass('Out');
   el.text("Open ↓");
   el.removeClass("clicked");
  } else {
   $('div').removeClass('Out');
   $('div').addClass('In');
   el.text("Close ↑");
   el.addClass("clicked");
  }
 }, 2000); // Will start after 2 seconds
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: pink;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
}

@keyframes In {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px
  }
}

@keyframes Out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 300px
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0
  }
}

.In {
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-name: In;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.Out {
  animation-duration: 800ms;
  animation-name: Out;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Open ↓ </button> <br>
<div> </div>
```

check working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/codething/sf9pgLh7/2/

Comment: I tried to add a delay, but it doesn't work : https://jsfiddle.net/sf9pgLh7/5/
Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: @user9018937368 We can always add setTimout to add some delay in animation start. Also note that i have made some changes in the js code like defined `$(this)` to the variable, so that we can reference the button inside setTimeout.